# Elementary OS Flatpak repository in other distros

Tags: linux-distributions, elementaryos, flatpak

I have read that [Elementary OS](https://elementary.io) already has a [Flatpak](https://flatpak.org/) repository.

If it is possible, how can it be used in other Linux distributions? (suppose they are already using flatpak with another repository like Flathub).

It is welcome if you could also provide a brief perspective on the advantages and disadvantages of this mix of repositories.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever distro you're on, if you have Flatpak already set up in your system and you want to use Elementary's Flatpak repo, add that repo using the below command:

```
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists --system appcenter https://flatpak.elementary.io/repo.flatpakrepo
```

Apps inside that repo would appear just the same as the apps inside Flathub.